# What's the solution for cocoa pods error when migrate to swift 3 and Xcode 8, issue details in the description?

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods, afnetworking, xcode8

After updating Xcode7 to Xcode 3 and migrate my code to swift 3, pods stopped working and show the following error.

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

1. I made sure the app is opened from the right icon.
2. I removed Afnetworking from Pods so it show same error in another one and so on.
3. I make sure the bit_enabled is set to yes.
4. I deleted the pod file, and workspace, everything related to pod and start over, same issue.

   5. I edited the scheme and nothing too.
   6. I removed and added `$(inherited)` again but nothing.
   7. removed Xcode and installed it again
   8. made sure the Xcode is looking to Xcode 8 commas line.

the cocoa pod version is `cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.3`

also here is the pods file

```
target 'MondoTaxiClient' do
```

# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

```
pod 'SocketRocket’, '~> 0.4'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.10.5'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.9'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
# pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.6'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Digits'
pod 'TwitterCore'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'APAddressBook/Swift', '~> 0.2'
pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 2.0.3'
pod 'Mixpanel', '~> 2.9'
pod 'Branch'
pod 'Adjust', '~> 4.6.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1'
end
```

the code target was iOS 7 + but after xcode 8 i made it iOS8+

if the solution is by downgrade cocoa pods please let me know which version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some of the pods are conflicting with some of the static SDKs, frameworks once the conflict is resolved the issue disappear